# Laravel 5.6 - Increase number when box is checked

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.6

So I've got this code :

```html
<div class="col-md-2">
  Services Available
  
  <div class="services">
    @foreach ($service as $service)
      <div class="service">
        <div id="checkboxes">
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="{{ $service->id }}" />
          <label class="whatever" for="{{ $service->id }}"><p class="serv-text"> {{ $service->service_name }} + ${{ $service->price }} </p></label>

        </div>
      </div>
    @endforeach

  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  Box Price
  <p div class="number">$0</p>
</div>
```

And I can't figure out how to make this work. I've tried with `js` too but didn't work.

So what I want to do is, when the user checks a box (each checkbox has a price in the database), the `class="number"` text must increase the number in real-time.

`$service->price` is the name of the checkbox price.

Comment: `{{ $service->service_name }} + ${{ $service->price }}` what you expect when you concate those values ? the finale service price ?

Comment: Actually if you want the number to increment live you will need to make use of javascript. Pure php will not be enough to display it live without refreshing the page.

Comment: Zakaria Acharki no that's just for displaying

Comment: isa424 I know I've tried using js too but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
  var v = parseInt($('#hidden').val())
  this.checked ? (v+=1) : (v-=1)
  $('#hidden').val(v)
  document.getElementById('num').innerHTML =v;  
  
  // call ajax to update the value in the server
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="checkbox" />
<input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="0">
<p class="number"> $<span id="num">0 </span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest putting the price inside a span so you could select it by class and perform the addition operation like :

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var number = 0;
  $(':checkbox:checked').each(function() {
    number += parseInt($(this).parent().find('.price').text());
  });
  $('.number').text('$' + number);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-2">
  Services Available

  <div class="services">
    <div class="service">
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="{{ $service->id }}" />
        <label class="whatever" for="{{ $service->id }}"><p class="serv-text">service_name 1 + $<span class="price">10</span></p></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service">
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="{{ $service->id }}" />
        <label class="whatever" for="{{ $service->id }}"><p class="serv-text">service_name 2 + $<span class="price">20</span></p></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="service">
      <div id="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="rGroup" value="1" id="{{ $service->id }}" />
        <label class="whatever" for="{{ $service->id }}"><p class="serv-text">service_name 3 + $<span class="price">50</span></p></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2">
  Box Price
  <p div class="number">$0</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't worry just update the question with your actual code after the change and we'll check with you.

Comment: Are you including the jQuery lib @GrosuDumitru ?